# Good conduct of including numbers in css classes

Tags: css

I'm creating a couple of dynamic css classes, and the idea is that i get a string from an episerver context and add that to the class list of an element.

I know that numbers can be included in css classes, but what is good css code conduct, is it a good idea to include numbers in class names, or should i change it from `body1 --> body-one.`

```
body1 {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
} 
body2 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

body-one {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
body-two {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

Comment: Neither is good. Instead of numbers use a suffix that describes the difference.

Comment: @RoToRa, I agree, the reason i created this was to get some consistency between what they input in their CMS, and the class that appears in the code, instead of having to guess what variable corolates in the CMS and the code.
Assume that i can't change the variables in the CMS since it's unchangeable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect naming in any language allowing freedom for your names are:

1. Descriptive. (Makes it clear what it means at a glance)
2. Short. (less chance for typos, types faster and therefore easier to work with.)

In your case, the names only mean to affect the text size. So appropriate names would be something like:

```css
text-medium {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
text-big {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

Since this makes it clear what they do.